# Regular Expression That Contains All Of The Specific Letters in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a dictionary list as a text files and want to select certain words that contains all of the members of a list of specific characters. Using the text editor **notepad++** to apply following *regular expression* on the dictionary list. I've tried the following *regular expression* statement on notepad++;

```
[BLT]+
```

However, this matches not all of the letters in the square brackets, but any of the letters in the square brackets. Then I've also tried the following regular expression, including the word boundary;

```
\b[BLT]+
```

And this expression, again, matches all the occurences of the words including **any**, but not **all** of the letters listed in between the square brackets.

## Desired Behaviour

Let say, the dictionary contains a list as below;

```
AL
BAL
BAK
LABAT
TAL
LAT
BALAT
LA
AB
LATAB
TAB
```

What I need is an expression that contains **all** of the the letters 'B','L','T' (not any!), thus **expected behaviour** should be as below;

```
LABAT
BALAT
LATAB
```

What is the **most minimalist** and **generic** *regular expression* for this problem?

Comment: And where are you stuck? Please share your regex.

Comment: You should take a look [here](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/7716)

Comment: If you can reword your question to comply with the [rules](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), you will do us both a favor. Otherwise this page will disappear on 2015-11-25.

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: The question is tagged with notepad++, also regular expression used in text editor is added, desired behaviour is added and clear, I dont understand why it is still on hold?

Comment: The problem is not the tagging with notepad++ (this is only marginally important), the problem is that you had not mentioned what you had tried and what problem you had encountered, mainly. SO wants to stay clear of people who ask others to do their homework. Now that you have fixed your question, only one vote for reopening is missing. If I were you, I would rearrange your question, though, putting your attempt to solution and the "where are you stuck" part (as @stribizhev said) last.

Comment: Updated again: Mentioned what I'd tried and encountered (Done), written attempted tryouts and stated the results that I've encountered (Done), desired behaviour (Added), did my homework with the help of stackoverflow: (done and I feel guilty)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
^(?=.*B)(?=.*L)(?=.*T).+$
```

As an example for a more general case, the optimized regex for at least 1 `B`, 2 `L`s and 3 `T`s:

```
^(?=[^B\n]*B)(?=(?:[^L\n]*L){2})(?=(?:[^T\n]*T){3}).+$
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning lookaheads.